How to retrieve current user session from RootLayout?
I am trying to handly a basic AppBar (using MUI) and i need to know if the user is logged in or not.
This AppBar is part of the RootLayout (and it seems to be the whole problem).
I can't find a "built-in" way to get the current user from the RootLayout, and i didn't find this use case from the document (from a page yes but not from the layout).
I am using next v14 and aws-amplify v6 by the way
I tried this very simple code example (this AppBar is not there bu the problem already appears with only that
import type { Metadata } from "next";
import { Inter } from "next/font/google";
import "./globals.css";

import { Authenticator } from "@aws-amplify/ui-react";

const inter = Inter({ subsets: ["latin"] });

export const metadata: Metadata = {
  title: "test title",
  description: "test descrition",
};

function RootLayout({
  children,
}: Readonly<{
  children: React.ReactNode;
}>) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body className={inter.className}>
        <Authenticator>
          {children}
        </Authenticator>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}

export default RootLayout;

I get this error:
 ⨯ ./node_modules/@aws-amplify/ui-react-core/dist/esm/components/FormCore/FormProvider.mjs Attempted import error: 'useForm' is not exported from 'react-hook-form' (imported as 'useForm').
If i remove the  wrapper, the error goes away

You can't access the user outside the  Component as that manages the state.
Where is your app bar situated?

Hi @DevonRay, i know i don't try to access from outside 
AppBar is in RootLayout but i already have a bug before i import it (that's what i explain in my post)

What if you create a separate component file with use client at the top where you return <Authenticator>{children}</Authenticator> and use it from your RootLayout?

<Authenticator /> component needs to be used in a client component. So you will need to create your own component with the authenticator code inside.
See the docs for more details:
https://docs.amplify.aws/nextjs/build-a-backend/server-side-rendering/nextjs-app-router-server-components/#configure-amplify-client-side
An example would be:
layout.
import type { Metadata } from "next";
import { Inter } from "next/font/google";
import "./globals.css";



const inter = Inter({ subsets: ["latin"] });

export const metadata: Metadata = {
  title: "test title",
  description: "test descrition",
};

function RootLayout({
  children,
}: Readonly<{
  children: React.ReactNode;
}>) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body className={inter.className}>
        <AppWithAuthenticator >{children}</AppWithAuthenticator>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}

export default RootLayout;


and AppWithAuthenticator.js
'use client'
import { Authenticator } from "@aws-amplify/ui-react";

export default function AppWithAuthenticator({children}) {


  return (
     <Authenticator>
       {children}
     </Authenticator>
  );
}



